# Network Emulation in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, testing, emulation

In the quest of testing my UDP, TCP/SCTP based data transport Project in a real-time environment I eventually landed on this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lkruger/archive/2009/06/08/introducing-true-network-emulation-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx):

So, has anybody tried this out? Actually I have a VS 2010 Pro edition copy (from Project Dream Spark).
And I am not able to even find the option to enable/select network emulation tests!? :(

Cheers,
echo9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all features are available in Pro edition.

Comment: But Network Emulation is for sure there! But its just that I am not able to get it out in front of my eyes..

Comment: I was able to load up the test impact property page (of a new empty test project I created) but I was shocked to see that there isn't any option for choosing the network emulation option :( or network agent

Comment: I guess u're right.. it must be available only in the Ultimate version :(

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool built on an earlier version of this technology called the Network Emulator Toolkit (NEWT). It allows you to emulate the conditions that would affect traffic traversing a network.

It's hard to find these days, but here is a link to it:

http://blog.mrpol.nl/2010/01/14/network-emulator-toolkit/

It's very simple to use and provides realistic emulation.

Comment: Hint: You'll need to enable the tracing button to see any of the statistics while running the emulation.